# Making a local copy of a database

Tags: mysql, database, datagrip

Currently I'm connecting to mysql databases on a dev server, but I want to make a copy of those databases on my local machine that I can connect to without connecting to the dev server. Is there an easy way to do this? I'm using DataGrip.

Thanks.

Comment: You didn't mention how synced you want the local databases to be to those in the dev server nor if it is ok to change the dev database from your local machine. An obvious solution would be to just dump the databases on the server and import them to your local machine. Other solutions would be syncing, replicating, using ssh and others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dump your schema from the context menu like on the picture

[image: You can dump your schema from the context menu like on the picture]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with DataGrip, but if you're using MYSQL, just log in on the website and go to your phpmyadmin, from there you can select the database you want, and click the EXPORT button, and you can choose the type of file to save it as. If DataGrip is a database tool, you should be able to save as an SQL file, otherwise maybe save as a CSV.